# Is it possible to perform Docker-call from a container into the host?

Tags: docker

I would like to be able to, e.g., restart host containers from inside a container.

Does anyone know whether there is any way I could do that?

Comment: Your question is not clear, try to make it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming that your question is "Is it possible to perform Docker-call from a container into the host?"*

Yeah, sure it is possible!
The communication with the Docker daemon goes through a socket. By default this socket is the `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. Your manager-container just need access (and permission) to this socket.

Note that an option of the Docker daemon (I'm looking at ou `-H, --host`) allows the communication through `TCP` (or even a `fd`).

You then just need a Docker client (any Docker API implementation) to communicate.

Comment: If it answers your question, I suggest that you tag my answer as valid, so your question is then tagged as answered (thus people having the problem will know the solution is available here ;) )