# Accessing docker port from inside docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I have a service running inside docker container on port 1234.
Now I want to run test for this service from the same docker container using

```
`docker exec`
```

But I can't do this because my test can not connect to it.
As service address I use docker $HOSTNAME variable.

```
docker exec SERVICE_NAME /bin/sh -c "nc -vz $HOSTNAME 1234"
```

returns

Connection refused

```
docker exec SERVICE_NAME /bin/sh -c "netstat -tulpn"
```

returns empty line

I also tried 0.0.0.0 insead of $HOSTNAME

I have already thought about running tests from other container but it is not very convenient to me because of two reasons:
1) I use gitlab ci with docker for this.
2) My service is linked to a number of other docker services like mongodb, rabbit etc.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate with [Is it possible to perform Docker-call from a container into the host?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35486335/5321002)?

Comment: `docker exec SERVICE_NAME /bin/sh -c "nc -vz $HOSTNAME 1234"` what do you expect this line will do? Can you ping "$HOSTNAME"? Is this host listening to the port 1234? If it is "a call from container into itself " then replace `$HOSTNAME` with `localhost`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to perform Docker-call from a container into the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485865/is-it-possible-to-perform-docker-call-from-a-container-into-the-host)

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming that your question is "Is it possible to perform Docker-call from a container into the host?"*

Yeah, sure it is possible!
The communication with the Docker daemon goes through a socket. By default this socket is the `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. You manager-container just need access (and permission) to this socket.

Not that an option of the Docker daemon (I'm looking at ou `-H, --host`) allows the communication through `TCP` (or even a `fd`).

You then just need a Docker client (any Docker API implementation) to communicate.

Comment: Not exact, I need to perform a call from container into itself